# Android Toast having Icon

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

In my app I am showing a toast message. But in One Plus One device it shows an icon on  left top corner(as shown in attached image).

Can any body help me how can I remove it ?[image]

Comment: Freaky custom OS. Just ignore it. The app that work great with good android devices will have lots of bugs in China made devices, just ignore it dude

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of Cyanogen OS/Cyanogenmod. You can not change this behaviour inside your app. Cyanogenmod will always show the App-Icon in this location. The only possible solution would be to provide a fully transparent App-Icon, this would result in your app having no icon at all.

Comment: Lots of Thanks Jonas for quick response.